# Using JsonUtility with PHP json array in unity

Tags: c#, php, json, database, unity-game-engine

I have trouble in using JsonUtility and php with json in Unity 5.5.1.

as it shows an error in unity saying this:

> ArgumentException: JSON parse error: Invalid value.
>       UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson[ItemDictionary] (System.String json)
>       (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/modules/JSONSerialize/JsonUtilityBindings.gen.cs:24)
>       DatabaseRead.LoadData (System.String val) (at Assets/Scripts/DatabaseRead.cs:40)
>       DatabaseRead+c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/DatabaseRead.cs:34)
>       UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress)
>       (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17)

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


[System.Serializable]
public class Item
{
   public string quizid;
   public string subject;
   public string question;
   public string answer;

}

[System.Serializable]
public class ItemDictionary
{
    public string[] items;
}

public class DatabaseRead : MonoBehaviour {

   public List<Item> items;

   IEnumerator Start()
   {
        WWW questionData = new WWW("localhost/game_dbase/questions.php");
        yield return questionData;

        string data = questionData.text;

        LoadData(data);

    }

    public void LoadData(string val)
    {
        ItemDictionary info = JsonUtility.FromJson<ItemDictionary>(val);

        foreach (string dictionaryitem in info.items)
        {

            LoadItem(dictionaryitem);
        }
    }


    public void LoadItem(string path)
    {
        string myLoadedItem = path;
        Item myItem = JsonUtility.FromJson<Item>(myLoadedItem);
        items.Add(myItem);
        Debug.Log(items);
    }

}
```

Php code:

```
<?php
$servername = @"localhost";
$username =  "root";
$password = "";
$dbName = "game_dbase";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);

if(!$conn){
    die("Connection Failed. ". mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT quizid, subjectid, question, answer FROM quiz";
$result = mysqli_query($conn ,$sql);

$json = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $json[]=  array(
        'quizid' => $row['quizid'],
        'subjectid' => $row['subjectid'],
        'question' => $row['question'],
        'answer' => $row['answer']
        );

    }

    $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
    echo "Items :";
    echo $jsonstring;

}
?>
```

`

Comment: And what was the content of questionData.text?

Comment: @Jeroen Heier 

>>Items :[{"quizid":"00001","subjectid":"001","question":"Known as the green planet","answer":"Earth"},{"quizid":"00002","subjectid":"001","question":"The Largest Planet in our solar system","answer":"Jupiter"},{"quizid":"00003","subjectid":"003","question":"A word that describes characteristics of a person, things, or places.","answer":"Adjective"}]